Why there is a background noise and echo when I start my stream?
I am trying to use webrtc in my web app, below is my code
const localVideoEl = document.getElementById("local-video");

const call = async (e) => {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  });
  localVideoEl.srcObject = stream;
};

document.getElementById("call").addEventListener("click", call);

The problem is as soon as the stream starts I get lot of background noise and echo. I tried with both headset and without it but same issue, I have a brand new MacBook and I have not changed any audio settings. When I use Microsoft Teams, Google Meet or Slack then I don't face such issue.

Did you try setting the echoCancellation and noiseSuppression properties of audio to true?

Yes I tried that as well but still same background noise

Unless your local-video element is muted you are asking it to play back the audio that is captured.

Mute local track (your self) while still being able to transmit it. Utilize echo cancellation and noise suppression; These features are supported widely. But as a developer would suggest making these options optional. Other than that nothing more you can do!

@PhilippHancke Local video element is not muted
